# Verifying card security code for returning customer

Tags: balanced-payments

Is there a way to re-validate a card using the card security code? I'd like to offer users to login with Facebook or to remember their login otherwise and I want to add an additional step during checkout to verify that the user is in possession of the credit card. I think some websites ask for the CSC again during checkout.

I could also ask for the user's password again, but I don't think that can work if the user logged in with Facebook.

Any suggestions around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it seems as if this kind of verification is not currently possible with Balanced. There is no API method to re-validate a card. Here are the solutions I came up with, just in case someone else has a similar problem:

1. Using a different piece of information to verify the user (card expiration date, etc). But that doesn't seem very common and would probably scare away some users.
2. Indeed forcing the user to enter the password again. No problem if the user uses a site-local login. In case the user is logged in using Facebook, there seems to be a way to force a re-authentication: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-re-auth/

Comment: Your best bet when the API doesn't support functionality that you want is to comment on github. https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/issues/11 - It helps us assess customer demand.